# C# Array number sorting

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I have an array of numbers jumbled up from 0-9.

How do I sort them in ascending order?

Array.Sort doesn't work for me. Is there another way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Array.Sort gives me this error.

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Array'

Right now it gives me this output:

0) VersionInfo.xml

2) luizafroes_singapore2951478702.xml

3) virua837890738.xml

4) darkwizar9102314425644.xml

5) snarterz_584609551.xml

6) alysiayeo594136055.xml

1) z-a-n-n2306499277.xml

7) zhangliyi_memories932668799030.xml

8) andy_tan911368887723.xml

9) config.xml

k are the numbers from 0-9

```
                    string[] valnames = rk2.GetValueNames();

                foreach (string k in valnames)
                {
                    if (k == "MRUListEx")
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    Byte[] byteValue = (Byte[])rk2.GetValue(k);

                    UnicodeEncoding unicode = new UnicodeEncoding();
                    string val = unicode.GetString(byteValue);

                    Array.Sort(k); //Error here
                    richTextBoxRecentDoc.AppendText("\n" + k + ") " + val + "\n");
                }
```

Comment: Array.Sort should work. Why is it not working? Could you extend the question please?

Comment: Just edited. How do I solve the problem?

Comment: What is the code you are running to create and sort the array?

Comment: "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Array'". You're probably not using an array of integers. int[] myNums = {3, 2, 8, 5, 4, 9};

Comment: Can you post the code, in addition to the error message? It shouldn't be more than 2 lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that k is not an Array but a string !

I have the feeling that this is what you want to do :

```
string[] valnames = rk2.GetValueNames();
valnames = valnames.OrderBy (s => int.Parse(s)).ToArray();

for (int i= 0 ; i < balnames.Lenght ; i++)
{
    k = valenames[i];
    if (k == "MRUListEx")
    {
        continue;
    }
    Byte[] byteValue = (Byte[])rk2.GetValue(k);

    UnicodeEncoding unicode = new UnicodeEncoding();
    string val = unicode.GetString(byteValue);

    richTextBoxRecentDoc.AppendText("\n" + i + ") " + val + "\n");
}
```

Comment: So how should I solve my problem? It gives me the numbers 0-9 though.

Comment: I'm not very sure of what you are trying to do but probably a Array.Sort(valnames) before the loop will do what you need isn't it ?

Comment: You can only use Array.Sort to sort arrays. A string is not an array. You need to re-think what the code is meant to be doing.

Comment: You should solve the problem by calling Array.Sort with an array, not with a string! (e.g. Array.Sort(byteValue);). Whatever it is you want to sort, it's almost certainly not k!

Comment: The output will be 1 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 2 21 22 23 24 25. How do I arrange it in ascending order?

Comment: Does not work. It says input string is not in correct format.

Comment: Do you have some special character there ?  maybe trim first ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have an array in integers or have you stored an array of System.Object, in which case you'll have problems with leading space.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to sort a String. That's not possible.

This code will give you the output you want:

```
string[] valnames = rk2.GetValueNames();

for (int i = valnames.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    string k = valnames[i];
    if (k == "MRUListEx")
        continue;

    Byte[] byteValue = (Byte[])rk2.GetValue(k);
    UnicodeEncoding unicode = new UnicodeEncoding();
    string val = unicode.GetString(byteValue);

    richTextBoxRecentDoc.AppendText("\n" + k + ") " + val + "\n");
}
```